# Scipy Optimize Function with Single Variable

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to use SciPy's minimize function to maximize the results of my function `f`. However, every time I run the script, I get the following error message.

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'float' object is not iterable
  File "C:\Users\DonzaJ\OneDrive - LiRo Group\Desktop\Personal Files\Python Code\Fence Angle Optimizer.py", line 24, in <module>
    theta_final = spo.minimize(f, theta, method = 'SLSQP', options ={'disp':True}, bounds = bdns)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Here is the script that I have set up so far.

```
import scipy.optimize as spo
import math as m
import numpy as np

# Define Constants
fenceLength = 7.5 #ft
pointLoad = 500 #lbs
ex2 = 2 #in
ey2 = 4 #in

# Define Initial Variables
theta = np.ndarray(45.0) #degrees

# Define bounds for theta
bdns = (0.0, 90.0)

def f(X, *args):
    ex1 = (fenceLength/2)*m.cos(m.radians(theta))
    ey1 = (fenceLength/2)*m.sin(m.radians(theta))
    Y = m.sqrt(((pointLoad*(ey1+ey2))**2 + (pointLoad*(ex1+ex2))**2)) * -1
    return Y

# Call minimizer 
theta_final = spo.minimize(f, theta, method = 'SLSQP', options ={'disp':True}, bounds = bdns)
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can fix this and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are using minimize, which is for 1D array. See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)

Comment: Please replace your screenshot of code with [formatted text](/help/formatting)

Comment: Apologies just replaced it with formatted text. Any suggestions for what function I could use that optimizes with only 1 variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of things wrong with your code.

1. `np.ndarray(45.0)` does not make a numpy array, you need to do something like `np.array([45.0])`. But, considering you only have one variable, you can just set `theta0 = 45.0`.
2. As mentioned in another answer, the bounds should be a sequence of pairs, meaning you should define it as `bnds = [(0.0, 90.0)]`.
3. Your `f` function needs to use the variable you are passing it, otherwise the optimizer will see no change in the results and assume it is already at a minimum. In other words, you should have `ex1 = (fenceLength/2)*m.cos(m.radians(X))`.
4. Your `theta_final` will not take the optimal value but will be an `OptimizerResult`, which you need to get the value from.

Below is the updated code that removes the numpy import, since it is unnecessary, makes the necessary changes outlined above, and updates some of the notation to be more standard.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import math

# Define Constants
fenceLength = 7.5 #ft
pointLoad = 500 #lbs
ex2 = 2 #in
ey2 = 4 #in

# Define Initial Variables
theta0 = 45.0 #degrees

# Define bounds for theta
bdns = [(0.0, 90.0)]

def f(X, *args):
    ex1 = (fenceLength/2)*math.cos(math.radians(X))
    ey1 = (fenceLength/2)*math.sin(math.radians(X))
    Y = -math.sqrt(((pointLoad*(ey1+ey2))**2 + (pointLoad*(ex1+ex2))**2))
    return Y

# Call minimizer 
res = minimize(f, theta0, method = "SLSQP", options={"disp":True}, bounds=bdns)
theta = res.x[0]
print(f"{theta = } deg")
```

Output:

```py
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -4111.067977477818
            Iterations: 4
            Function evaluations: 8
            Gradient evaluations: 4
theta = 63.43457272808145 deg
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the bounds param.
As the documentation says:

> bound : sequence or Bounds, optional Bounds on variables for
> Nelder-Mead, L-BFGS-B, TNC, SLSQP, Powell, trust-constr, and COBYLA
> methods. There are two ways to specify the bounds:
>
> 1. Instance of Bounds class.
> 2. Sequence of (min, max) pairs for each element in x. None is used to
>    specify no bound.

You were attempting to use the second option, but you only have a tuple instead of a sequence of tuple. An easy fix would be:

```
# Define bounds for theta
bdns = [(0.0, 90.0)]
```

Comment: Yes that worked! However, when I began to run my script, no matter what value I put into my "theta" variable, the minimize function only loops through once and returns practically the same "theta" value that I set it at with a different "Y" value each time. I would suspect that I should get the same "Y" value each time. Why is my minimize function not finding the smallest value?

Comment: @Jdonza The function does not reference the variable X, so f(45) and f(50) return the same value. Instead it references theta, which is set to a constant.